Issue with RNFusedLocation.getCurrentPosition after upgrading React Native to version 0.74.3
I'm encountering a problem after upgrading my React Native project to version 0.74.3. The application was working fine on version 0.64.4, but after the upgrade, I get an error when trying to use RNFusedLocation.getCurrentPosition
**Project configuration details :
**
React Native Version: ^0.74.3 (was working fine on ^0.64.4)
Google Play Services Location Version: 21.3.0
Library used: "react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.3.1"

**Gradle Configuration:
**
googlePlayServicesLocationVersion = "21.3.0" . implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.3.0'
**Error message:
**
`Could not invoke RNFusedLocation.getCurrentPosition

null

Found interface com.google.android.gms.location.SettingsClient, but class was expected
(declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.location.SettingsClient' appears in /data/app/...)
`

I tried updating the Google Play Services versions in my project. Initially, I had:
googlePlayServicesLocationVersion = "21.3.0"  // Or higher.
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.3.0'

I then tried downgrading to:
googlePlayServicesVersion = "17.0.0"
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.3.0'

However, despite these changes, the issue still persists.

For some reason, Geolocation has been extracted from this react-native version I guess. I'm using the version .75, and I faced the same error for the code,
Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                (position) => {
                    console.log('Current position:', position);
                },
                (error) => {
                    console.error('Geolocation error:', error);
                    Alert.alert('Error', 'Unable to retrieve location.');
                },
                { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 15000, maximumAge: 10000 }
            );

Instead of react-native-geolocation-service package I installed and used @react-native-community/geolocation package.
npm install @react-native-community/geolocation --save

Then
import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation';

That's all I had to change to fix the issue. Hope this will help.
